# Pregunta Juego Encontrar Objetos Java

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe

Estoy realizando un juego de objetos ocultos en java, donde tengo una interfaz con bastantes label(30 o mas) que poseen una imagen, y la interfaz también tiene 5 botones los cuales tienen los nombres de 5 imágenes de la interfaz, y con esos nombres buscar la imagen y darle click y que desaparezca, y posterior a eso que el botón cambie de nombre a otra imagen después de que se encontró un objeto, par ser mas exacta es como algo parecido al famoso juego Criminal Case, mi problema es que ya implemente todo el código como se muestra a continuación, no me sale ningún error pero no hacen bien las funciones que deberían hacer, en el código me aparecen los métodos subrayados con amarillo no se si sea eso.. Alguien me podria ayudar?

```
public class Ventana extends javax.swing.JFrame {
boolean estado;
int contar;
String nombre;

 public Ventana(){
     initComponents();
 }                                              

    private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
       estado=false;
       Inicio();
    }                                 

    private void jButton6MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    estado=true;
    Inicio();
    jButton6.setVisible(false);
     jButton1.setText("Pecera");
     jButton2.setText("Cartas");
         jButton3.setText("Tijeras");
       jButton4.setText("oso");
        jButton5.setText("Candado");
    }                                     

    private void peceraMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
          if(jButton1.getText()== "Pecera" || jButton2.getText()=="Pecera" || jButton3.getText()=="Pecera" || jButton4.getText()=="Pecera" || jButton5.getText()=="Pecera"){
           pecera.setVisible(false);
            nombre="Perry";
            CleanBoton();
            contar+=1;
            CalculoNombre();
            CalcularSiguiente();
                    }
    }                                   

    private void cartaMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
        if(jButton1.getText()== "Cartas" || jButton2.getText()=="Cartas" || jButton3.getText()=="Cartas" || jButton4.getText()=="Cartas" || jButton5.getText()=="Cartas"){
           pecera.setVisible(false);
            nombre="Cartas";
            CleanBoton();
            contar+=1;
            CalculoNombre();
            CalcularSiguiente();
                    }
    }                                  

    private void tijeraMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
        if(jButton1.getText()== "Tijeras" || jButton2.getText()=="Tijeras" || jButton3.getText()=="Tijeras" || jButton4.getText()=="Tijeras" || jButton5.getText()=="Tijeras"){
           pecera.setVisible(false);
            nombre="Tijeras";
            CleanBoton();
            contar+=1;
            CalculoNombre();
            CalcularSiguiente();
                    }
    }                                   

    private void candadoMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        if(jButton1.getText()== "Candado" || jButton2.getText()=="Candado" || jButton3.getText()=="Candado" || jButton4.getText()=="Candado" || jButton5.getText()=="Candado"){
           pecera.setVisible(false);
            nombre="Candado";
            CleanBoton();
            contar+=1;
            CalculoNombre();
            CalcularSiguiente();
                    }
    }                                    

    private void osoMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                 
       if(jButton1.getText()== "oso" || jButton2.getText()=="oso" || jButton3.getText()=="oso" || jButton4.getText()=="oso" || jButton5.getText()=="oso"){
           pecera.setVisible(false);
            nombre="Perry";
            CleanBoton();
            contar+=1;
            CalculoNombre();
            CalcularSiguiente();
                    }
    }                                

    private void Inicio(){
    reloj.setVisible(estado);
    globo.setVisible(estado);
    pajaro.setVisible(estado);
    avion.setVisible(estado);
    estrella.setVisible(estado);
    cuadro.setVisible(estado);
    espejo.setVisible(estado);
    mono.setVisible(estado);
    puerta.setVisible(estado);
    encendedor.setVisible(estado);
    escalera.setVisible(estado);
    percheo.setVisible(estado);
    alfombra.setVisible(estado);
    terraquio.setVisible(estado);
    estambre.setVisible(estado);
    gato.setVisible(estado);
    perro.setVisible(estado);
    hueso.setVisible(estado);
    llaves.setVisible(estado);
    tijera.setVisible(estado);
    libro.setVisible(estado);
    periodico.setVisible(estado);
    pecera.setVisible(estado);
    cuchara.setVisible(estado);
    manzana.setVisible(estado);
    mesa.setVisible(estado);
    tabrete.setVisible(estado);
    plato.setVisible(estado);
    florero.setVisible(estado);
    lampara.setVisible(estado);
    fosforo.setVisible(estado);
    monopoly.setVisible(estado);
    equipo.setVisible(estado);
    burbuja.setVisible(estado);
    camisa.setVisible(estado);
    cama.setVisible(estado);
    candado.setVisible(estado);
    carro.setVisible(estado);
    carta.setVisible(estado);
    casa.setVisible(estado);
    celular.setVisible(estado);
    cereal.setVisible(estado);
    colgate.setVisible(estado);
    escoba.setVisible(estado);
    flores.setVisible(estado);
    jabon.setVisible(estado);
    gancho.setVisible(estado);
    lavamanos.setVisible(estado);
    lavadora.setVisible(estado);
    perro.setVisible(estado);
    licuadora.setVisible(estado);
    navidad.setVisible(estado);
    oso.setVisible(estado);
    pantalon.setVisible(estado);
    pila.setVisible(estado);
    portatil.setVisible(estado);
    televisor.setVisible(estado);
    toalla.setVisible(estado);
    zapato.setVisible(estado);
    jButton1.setVisible(estado);
    jButton2.setVisible(estado);
    jButton3.setVisible(estado);
    jButton4.setVisible(estado);
    jButton5.setVisible(estado);
    }

    public void CleanBoton(){
    if(jButton1.getText()==nombre){
       jButton1.setText("");
    }else
    if(jButton2.getText()==nombre){
       jButton2.setText("");
    }else
        if(jButton3.getText()==nombre){
       jButton3.setText("");
        }else
        if(jButton4.getText()==nombre){
       jButton4.setText("");
        }else
        if(jButton5.getText()==nombre){
       jButton5.setText("");
        }
}
    public void CalculoNombre(){
           if(contar==1){
        nombre="Pila";
    }else
    if(contar==2){
        nombre="Gato";
    }else
    if(contar==3){
        nombre="Pantalon";
    } else
    if(contar==4){
        nombre="Jabon";
    }else
    if(contar==5){
        nombre="Lavadora";
    }
    if(contar>=6){
       nombre=" "; 
    }      
    }

  public void CalcularSiguiente(){
       if( jButton1.getText()==" "){
        jButton1.setText(nombre);
    }else
        if(jButton2.getText()==" "){
            jButton2.setText(nombre);
        }else
        if(jButton3.getText()==" "){
            jButton3.setText(nombre);
        }else
        if(jButton4.getText()==" "){
            jButton4.setText(nombre);
        }else
        if(jButton5.getText()==" "){
            jButton5.setText(nombre);
        }
  }


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel alfombra;
    private javax.swing.JLabel avion;
    private javax.swing.JLabel burbuja;
    private javax.swing.JLabel cama;
    private javax.swing.JLabel camisa;
    private javax.swing.JLabel candado;
    private javax.swing.JLabel carro;
    private javax.swing.JLabel carta;
    private javax.swing.JLabel casa;
    private javax.swing.JLabel celular;
    private javax.swing.JLabel cereal;
    private javax.swing.JLabel colgate;
    private javax.swing.JLabel cuadro;
    private javax.swing.JLabel cuchara;
    private javax.swing.JLabel encendedor;
    private javax.swing.JLabel equipo;
    private javax.swing.JLabel escalera;
    private javax.swing.JLabel escoba;
    private javax.swing.JLabel espejo;
    private javax.swing.JLabel estambre;
    private javax.swing.JLabel estrella;
    private javax.swing.JLabel florero;
    private javax.swing.JLabel flores;
    private javax.swing.JLabel fosforo;
    private javax.swing.JLabel gancho;
    private javax.swing.JLabel gato;
    private javax.swing.JLabel globo;
    private javax.swing.JLabel hueso;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jabon;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lampara;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lavadora;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lavamanos;
    private javax.swing.JLabel libro;
    private javax.swing.JLabel licuadora;
    private javax.swing.JLabel llaves;
    private javax.swing.JLabel manzana;
    private javax.swing.JLabel mesa;
    private javax.swing.JLabel mono;
    private javax.swing.JLabel monopoly;
    private javax.swing.JLabel navidad;
    private javax.swing.JLabel oso;
    private javax.swing.JLabel pajaro;
    private javax.swing.JLabel pantalon;
    private javax.swing.JLabel pecera;
    private javax.swing.JLabel percheo;
    private javax.swing.JLabel periodico;
    private javax.swing.JLabel perro;
    private javax.swing.JLabel pila;
    private javax.swing.JLabel plato;
    private javax.swing.JLabel portatil;
    private javax.swing.JLabel puerta;
    private javax.swing.JLabel reloj;
    private javax.swing.JLabel tabrete;
    private javax.swing.JLabel televisor;
    private javax.swing.JLabel terraquio;
    private javax.swing.JLabel tijera;
    private javax.swing.JLabel toalla;
    private javax.swing.JLabel zapato;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Java y JavaScript son dos lenguajes de programación distintos. Sólo deben incluirse las etiquetas de ambos cuando se la pregunta trate sobre los dos lenguajes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás comparando objetos de tipo `String` con `==`, debes hacerlo con el método `.equals("tuString")`.

Cambia `jButton1.getText()== "Pecera"` por `"Pecera".equals(jButton1.getText())`, `jButton2.getText()=="Candado"` por `"Candado".equals(jButton2.getText())`, etc...